# Renamed Google Apps User and Sync. How to reconfigure?

Tags: google-apps

Since renaming his Google apps account, one of my employees Droid Razr can't sync. I'm sure it's still pointing to the old user name. He is running 4.0.4 on his Razr.

Can he reconfigure his device without wiping it? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a primary google account? - if it is, a factory reset would be needed, meaning a wipe unfortunately...

Comment: Maybe he could simply add a "secondary" account? I never played with that, but shouldn't it work as well?

Comment: Adding secondary should work as well. Add second account disable sync for first account.